# Spring Batch read files with arbitrary length

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement where the file format is arbitrary. Both of the format specified in the below image are valid

[image: sample record]

Basically the token name ( except the first column `User Name`) and number of token is arbitrary. Is it possible to create a reader in Spring batch to read both files ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FlatFileItemReader` with a custom `LineTokenizer` that handles the dynamism.

Otherwise, you have to go one level above and implement a custom `ItemReader`.